# The best way to remove floats in in inline style for elements using PHP?

Tags: php, css, inline

As I am making mobile version of my database driven website. Can you please tell whats the best way to filter all floats inside inline style attributes of elements using PHP ?

Comment: PHP is server-side code. Normally it will simply create the HTML, including tags referring to other JS and CSS files which then handle the styling and interactions on a page. Using PHP to manipulate inline style attributes is a flawed idea. Inline styles should be avoided, where possible, and CSS stylesheets used instead. Then, if really necessary, you could use PHP to include/exclude a CSS class (or similar) to the `<body>` tag, with CSS selectors then handling the presentation from that point onwards.

Comment: @Lucanos Since the user have used tinyMCE to create HTML document and saved them in database, I have to run such a manipulation before publishing those DB stored HTML

Comment: @MohammadRahmani Might you are better off looking for a tinyMCE plugin or similar to filter the content before storing it in the DB?

Comment: @Lucanos No, because I both need the original version and mobile version. I am thinking of a caching system - once I manipulate and save and I will reuse it in future. But that's a future project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// $rawHTML : This is the assumed variable containing the HTML to be filtered/displayed

$filteredHTML = preg_replace(
  array(
    '/style=["\'](.*)float\s*:\s*(?:left|right|none);?\s*(.*)["\']/' ,
    '/\s*style=["\']{2}/'
  ) ,
  array(
    'style="$1$2"' ,
    ''
  ) ,
  $rawHTML
);
```

This code will produce the following:

```
$rawHTML = '<div style="float:left">Whatever</div>';
$filteredHTML = '<div>Whatever</div>'
```

It will also leave any other styles untouched

```
$rawHTML = '<div style="float:left;color:red">Whatever</div>';
$filteredHTML = '<div style="color:red">Whatever</div>'
```

and

```
$rawHTML = '<div style="font-weight:bold;float:left;color:red">Whatever</div>';
$filteredHTML = '<div style="font-weight:bold;color:red">Whatever</div>'
```

Comment: absolutely great solution.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such command I guess, the best way to read the file using `fopen` command in php and `find-replace` the css key values.. and include the output into you mobile version page.

Comment: I have the whole html string in a PHP variable, it is not in an HTML file, all Html content live in DB. So it's all available in PHP. I need a regexp or PHPDOMDocument trick to wipe those floats before publish them in public

Comment: What's the problem then, if you have the data in PHP variable then simply overwrite the variable again after applying the regx (find and replace globla occurance) and leave the variable as it is.. Is it making any sense or I am not understanding what the process is?

Comment: actually I was looking for the right regex and thanks to Lucanos, I have it now.